# Thread safe of storm bolt

Tags: multithreading, apache-storm

I have a bolt which will collecting data from other bolts. Once there is enough data in the bolt or the time clock has reached, this bolt will do some time-consuming jobs based on collected data.

My question is, during the time-consuming jobs, other bolts should keep sending data to this bolt, would this cause a thread-safe problem? Do I need add a lock when running time-consuming jobs?

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349152/how-is-this-word-count-bolt-thread-safe), but I don't understand the answer.

Considering word-count bolt below and let's say it has only one instance, when one message has reached this bolt, it will acked at once. Since the Map is empty, it will then launch a time-consuming job. In the meanwhile, in my understanding, other spouts/bolts are still running now and keep sending messages to this bolt. However, since the first message is not put to map yet, these new messages will launch the time-consuming job again and again. Wouldn't this cause a thread-safe issue?

```
public static class WordCount extends BaseRichBolt {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
      collect.ack(tuple); // ack upon receiving the message
      String word = tuple.getString(0);
      Integer count = counts.get(word); 
      if (count == null){
        // doing time-consuming job here
        count = 0;
      }
      count++;
      counts.put(word, count);
      collector.emit(new Values(word, count));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Some comments/advice regarding your code: you could use a Batch bolt which is made for exactly these scenarios (collecting data and batch exectuion). You should ack _after_ the data is processed and not before (see examples [here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storm Bolts are thread safe ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/IS8PijLjU8c)).
Sending data to bolts while they perform time conusming operations is ok. You can whatch capacity of your bolt in Storm UI and if it struggles, just increase paralelism.

Comment: Considering an instance of bolts, if the execute function is doing time-consuming jobs, will there be another execute call by other bolts/spout? What is the time-consuming job acked at first?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question. I don't understand what you want to ask.

Comment: I added an example. Hope it is easier to understand my question.

Comment: All will be fine. Each instance of bolt run 'execute()' method synchronously.  Bolt wount call 'execute()' on new tuple untill previos finished. Capacity metric calculated on this. (tuples executed * avg execute time) / time

Comment: Cool! That make sense!